# How to load iwlwifi driver?

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, firmware

My Linux system can't detect my wireless driver, so I have to load it manually.

I know what my driver is and tried this method:

> Installation of the firmware is simply:
>
> ```
>  % cp iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode /lib/firmware
> ```
>
> You can now load the driver!

So I have successively copied the driver in the proper location `/lib/firmware` but I don't know what is meant by **TO LOAD THE DRIVER**. I thought that simply copying the driver into `/lib/firmware` would do the trick but NO it should be loaded into the kernel as is written in the instruction.

**But how am I supposed to load this driver, what should I do to load    it?**

---

Here is what I did:

```
root@gNewSense:/home/georgi# modprobe -r iwlwifi
root@gNewSense:/home/georgi# modprobe iwlwifi
root@gNewSense:/home/georgi# lsmod | grep iwl
iwlwifi               162535  0 
mac80211              192806  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              137243  2 mac80211,iwlwifi

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:08b2] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:c270]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:380d]

$ dmesg | grep iwl

$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
...
```

Hopefully there is some clue in this output!

Excuse me for not mentioning it at the beginning but the GNU system that is `gNewSense` (it is `Debian` based) not `Ubuntu`. Anyway after reboot gives me this:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl

$ uname -r
3.2.0-4gnewsense1-amd64
```

Also the official driver info in `gNewSense` pages is:
[it isn't work with a free driver](https://h-node.org/wifi/view/en/1746/Intel-Corporation-Wireless-7260--rev-bb-)

Comment: Please reboot and the edit to show: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `uname -r`

Comment: Your device is not supported until kernel version 3.10 and later. You are running 3.2 and not running Ubuntu. Sorry that we cannot help further. https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

Comment: Maybe only It seems like the package `linux-firmware` is missing?

try 

    `apt install linux-firmware`

and reboot.

This worked for me. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1064139/34298

Comment: If you dual boot with windows 10 it might be that the wifi card is somehow blocked by windows. To avoid this happening use "shutdown /s /f /t 0" in a command shell in windows (I created a .bat file with this content, and so just can double click it to shutdown). I know it sounds ridiculous, but as soon as I do the full shutdown it works under Ubuntu...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can load the driver with:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

The driver *iwlwifi* and, indeed, the required firmware are included by default in all recent Ubuntu versions. If it is not loaded, something else is wrong.

Is yours really an *iwlwifi* device? Check:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

Is the switch or key combination set to enable or disable the wireless? Check:

```
rfkill list all
```

Are there any clues in the log?

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

After we find out more, I will edit this question to add additional troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 14):

The absolutely simplest way is to reboot. This ensures that all modules are loaded cleanly, on boot.

The other alternative is to manually remove it:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
```

and reinsert it it

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

But iwlwifi typically has a couple of modules that depends on it, so it may be easier to reboot, if `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` returns any errors.

To see dependencies, run `lsmod | grep iwl`

```
[~]$ lsmod | grep iwl
iwlmvm                364544  0 
mac80211              782336  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               180224  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              610304  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
[~]$
```

In this case iwlmvm depends on iwlwifi, so it has to be removed as well.