# ubuntu 20.04 latest cannot find my wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 20.10

I just bought a new machine and put the latest Ubuntu on there, and cannot see my WiFi. `nmcli` showed only localhost and ethernet... no WiFi at all.

I've searched high and low, and at least have found the commands that I can run to hopefully help you help me ;)

Looks like it's getting error code `-110` on  `iwlwifi`, and the commands I ran show that the network is `UNCLAIMED`, not sure if that's a clue.

UPDATE: I downloaded the AX200 driver from https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html and `cp`'d the file into `/lib/firmware`, and followed [How to load iwlwifi driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990363/how-to-load-iwlwifi-driver).

UPDATE 2: I reinstalled Ubuntu with "Install 3rd party software for graphics and wifi hardware" checkbox... still no dice.

UPDATE 3: Re-installed 20.04 (to avoid issues w 20.10) and still all the same issues.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Here is the `dmesg` to give us some clues:

```
username@myhostname:~$ sudo dmesg | grep wifi
[    4.935758] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.015538] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:06:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Here is the `lspci` info to get the hardware info:

```
username@myhostname:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 02)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Here is the `uname` info:

```
username@myhostname:~$ uname -a
Linux myhostname 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 21 22:29:16 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This shows the `UNCLAIMED` network for the WiFi:

```
username@myhostname:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc400000-fc403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 02
       serial: 24:4b:fe:56:e0:c7
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k duplex=full ip=192.168.1.228 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:38 memory:fc200000-fc2fffff memory:fc300000-fc303fff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it! I had to 1. load the correct module, and the missing item that took me days to figure out was 2. disable secure boot. Details below:

For Kernel 5.4, install iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode for AX200, it is available from zip file at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/commit/?id=2ae99744efc14

cd into `/lib/firmware` and remove the iwlwifi-cc-a0-60.ucode:

```
sudo rm -f iwlwifi-cc-a0-60.ucode
```

then copy over the right one

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode /lib/firmware
```

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

if you are facing this error modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Operation not permitted

The solution is to disabled the Secure Boot. Firstly check if SecureBoot is enabled on Ubuntu.

Install mokutil

```
sudo apt-get install mokutil
```

and check the status of SecureBoot

```
mokutil --sb-state
```

In case it is enabled run command

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Reboot. Then verify wifi works!

Then, re-enable secure boot again:

```
sudo mokutil --enable-validation
```

#### credits and links

["Operation not permitted" when trying to `modprobe xpad`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114867/operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-modprobe-xpad)

[Ubuntu: "Booting in insecure mode" with SecureBoot enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726052/ubuntu-booting-in-insecure-mode-with-secureboot-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago one of my friend had the same problem, he fixed it by installing an additional driver for his wifi adapter.

He followed these steps

1. Open Sofware & Updates application, there you will find drivers for your wifi card

[image: Additional Driver Screenshot]

2. Install it.

Comment in this answer if this works for your (it worked for my friend).

Comment: thanks for the response! Unfortunately, there are no drivers there except for my graphics card.

Comment: I've added sceenshot of my friend's laptop, maybe it can help little bit.